Seinen manga about girl who sees giant in the sky and boy who reads her diary
Sure facts:
It about highschool or middle school boy who had notebook that text appeared to everytime his crush wrote something in her diary. She saw a massive person floating in the sky and was under impression he did too because he faked having things in common with her using the notebook.
I think these were also a thing but I am not 100% sure:
She refered to it as an angel. She started to preach something weird about it. Layout of either first chapter or first few: The story started with them in school him talking to his friends. Then he figured out the notebook thing. They started to get closer and the diary entries became weirder and weirder. They were on hill and he said something referencing the diary which started the angel(?) conversation. It continued but I stopped reading at that point. To my memory it was tagged fantasy or sci-fi but I cannot recall which.
It had black and white art with, to my memory, pretty typical 2010s psychological(?) seinen artstyle. I read few chapters of it about 4 years ago and I can't find it anymore due to there being bigger series with similar key words.

This is Babel no Toshokan.

Meet Watase, an awkward teen with an unusual power over the written word. One day he uses that power to do something impossible, which draws the attention of Aiba, a girl he finds interesting. But Aiba lives in a secret world of her own devising, believing that the world around her is a lie. And so Watase’s impossible act seems like fate to Aiba, and sets the pair down an unexpected path.

The manga opens with the protagonist and the girl he has a crush on being called in to a teacher's office for potentially cheating. The two submitted a 500 or so word essay, word-for-word identical.
The protagonist has some manner of power over written words, which he uses to peek on her dairy and cheat in exams - he's shown to be fairly clueless schoolwise, but always tops written tests because he's able to get the right answers despite not knowing the material.
The two are forced to rewrite the essay and decide to test if the essay thing was a coincidence or fate - they both write something separately on a piece of paper without showing the other. Both write "The secret path of angels".
The backstory where the girl sees the angel is in chapter 6.

The girl is convinced that he is also aware of angels.

There are only 10 chapters, so it's possible you read the entire thing.

Could this be Marie no Kanaderu Ongaku?

In a surreal world of abundant wonders, Gil is a workshop town specialized in mechanical craftsmanship, boasting the largest population in the land of Piril. People lead simple lives with little to no advancement in technology, worshipping Marie, a mechanical Goddess who keeps vigil of Piril from the sky.
Daughter of the top mechanical artisan of Gil, Pipi is a cheerful and popular young girl. She likes her childhood friend, Kai, who has an extraordinary ability to hear sounds inaudible to the human ear. He is the only one in town who can listen to Marie's "music." The soothing sounds that come from her are said to retain the peace and harmony of the land. Kai's affection for Marie deepens as he continues to experience these sounds and see visions of himself through her eyes.



I like that one but no. It had modern setting.
